# Valid regex for http.nonProxyHosts

Tags: java, regex, proxy

I want to set up `nonProxyHosts` through System properties.
I want all the HTTP URLS to be accessed directly except two URLS. For this, instead of configuring all the host names for `nonProxyHosts`, which is `risky`
Can I configure this through a regular expression which gives all URLS minus the URLS that are to be `proxied`.

Can my regex be something like this?

```
http.nonProxyHosts=[^*host1*]|[^*host2*]
```

Comment: between `host1` and `host2` which you use to pass in `nonPoxyHost`? any method to choose one? that part is little confusing for me

Comment: Hi Jubin, I want both  host1 and host to be proxied. and rest all http requests as non proxied. I have a complex application so that I cannot list all the http hosts in non proxy. So I am looking for a way where I can use a negation kind of thing in the non proxy hosts regular expression

Comment: oh that mean you say you have all `host` in one string and you have to divide them separate

Comment: Yes Jubin exactly. * would get all the hosts (correct me if I am wrong). And use a regular expression with negation to get a regex [all urls - specific host]. This is because my application makes http requests to many hosts and there is a chance that I may miss configuring them in the nonProxyHosts. So I am looking for this approach.

Comment: Did this ever work?

Answer (score 1):

```
protected Pattern createNonProxyPattern(String nonProxyHosts) {
        if (nonProxyHosts == null || nonProxyHosts.equals("")) return null;

        // "*.fedora-commons.org" -> ".*?\.fedora-commons\.org" 
        nonProxyHosts = nonProxyHosts.replaceAll("\\.", "\\\\.").replaceAll("\\*", ".*?");

        // a|b|*.c -> (a)|(b)|(.*?\.c)
        nonProxyHosts = "(" + nonProxyHosts.replaceAll("\\|", ")|(") + ")";

        try {
            return Pattern.compile(nonProxyHosts);

            //we don't want to bring down the whole server by misusing the nonProxy pattern
            //therefore the error is logged and the web client moves on.
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log
                    .error("Creating the nonProxyHosts pattern failed for http.nonProxyHosts="
                            + nonProxyHosts
                            + " with the following exception: "
                            + e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

get full info/code from [here](https://svn.duraspace.org/fcrepo-mirror/moved-to-github/fedora/branches/fcrepo-604/fcrepo-common/src/main/java/fedora/common/http/ProxyConfiguration.java)
with this way you can get one nonproxy Pattern. For two you have to change return type of function to `TRUE/FALSE` and then it will go OK.

Comment: You can just use `Pattern.quote()`

Comment: The above code says that I have to pass the non proxy hosts as param to the constructor of the Class. But my requirement is that, all my requests should be non proxy except for two urls. So I am checking for a regex which gives [all hosts] - [one host]

`Something like *|[^*proxyhost*]`

Comment: this not necessary to pass `param` to class, with `for` loop OR `while` loop you can check one by one all your `non proxy host` which one you get right stop the process from that and use that.you have to use this method to find is it`nonproxy` or not.